# Getting row values from gridview checkbox

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I know this is an old topic, but none of the solutions I find seem to help. I am new at this, so please guide me:
I am making a call to a database to retrieve records that are then displayed in a gridview along with a checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked, I need to save the checked row records into a separate table along with some other queried information in the insert statement. The issue is that the firstname and lastname are not getting populated, resulting in the null exception. Can anyone review this and let me know how to resolve it?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Partial Class scores
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Me.GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
Protected Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim chkrow As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("cb1"), CheckBox)
        If chkrow.Checked = True Then
            Dim firstname As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("firstname"), TextBox)
            Dim lastname As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lastname"), TextBox)
            Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVERNAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ME;Password=PASSWORD;Initial Catalog=Testing"
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into scores (date, test, score, personid, testid) Values (getdate(), @test, @score, (select personid from persons where firstname = '" + firstname.Text + "' and lastname = '" + lastname.Text + "'), (select testid from tests where testnm ='" + DDL2.SelectedValue + "'))"
            conn.Open()
            Try
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DDL2.SelectedValue
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@score", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Score.Text
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Response.Write("Saved")
            Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                conn.Close()
            End Try
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

And the markup page:

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="scores.aspx.vb" Inherits="scores" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            Scores<br /><br />
            Pick tester name <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="personid" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CB1" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="personid" HeaderText="personid" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="personid" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" SortExpression="Firstname" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Lastname" HeaderText="Lastname" SortExpression="Lastname" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Social" HeaderText="Social" SortExpression="Social" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Testing %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [personid], [Firstname], [Lastname], [Social] FROM [Persons] where [personid] not in (select personid from scores) ORDER BY [Lastname]  "></asp:SqlDataSource>
            Test taken <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="TestNM" DataValueField="TestNM"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Testing %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TestNM], [testid] FROM [Tests] ORDER BY [TestNM]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            Score <asp:TextBox ID="Score" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you are re-binding all the data (in Page_Load) before attempting to read it. Try checking for postback first:

```
If Not Page.IsPostback Then
    Me.GridView1.DataBind()
End If
```

Comment: No change when this code is added. As I step through the code, the firstname and lastname are not getting populated, so still getting the object reference not set to the instance of an object. The stack trace indicated the sql query, but that query runs fine when I replace the variables in query analyzer.